# How to get currently queried elements in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

for example if I have

```
<img class="fr-box-wrapper"></img>
<img class="fr-box-wrapper"></img>
<img class="fr-box-wrapper"></img>
<img class="fr-box-wrapper"></img>
<img class="fr-box-wrapper"></img>
<img class="fr-box-wrapper"></img>
```

now I do a

```
this.magnify.click(function(e){
  $('.fr-box-wrapper').attr({
    "origwidth": $(this).width(), // this is wrong
    "origheight": $(this).height() // this is wrong
  }).css({
    position: "fixed",
    top: "0",
    left: "0",
    width: $(document).width(),
    height: $(document).height(),
    background: "white",
    overflow: "auto"
  });
});
```

how do I get width and height of each `$('.fr-box-wrapper')`?

Comment: What you want to achieve here. and what is this.magify?

Comment: Hi aero you want to get the width and height of each $('.fr-box-wrapper') or you want to get for a particular clicked element height and width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.fr-box-wrapper').each(function(){
  $(this).attr({
    "origwidth": $(this).width(),
    "origheight": $(this).height()
  }).css({
    position: "fixed",
    top: "0",
    left: "0",
    width: $(document).width(),
    height: $(document).height(),
    background: "white",
    overflow: "auto"
  });
});
```